# this does not refer to viewmodel in binding from observableArray template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Trying to use the new [cleaner event handling](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/) in Knockout 2 along with the new control flow bindings I'm working on implementing a simple dynamic list, adding and removing strings.  So my markup roughly looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:myList">
    <input data-bind="value: $data" />
    <button data-bind="click:$parent.removeFromList">X</button>
</div>
```

and my viewmodel has a matching remove function which immitates [a sample from Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/).

```
removeFromList: function(item) {
    this.myList.remove(item);
}
```

Now I would expect 'this' to refer to the viewmodel and item to refer to the array member being removed (since [event handlers now receive the current model value as their first parameter](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/)).  However, 'this' also seems to refer to the string being removed.  Therefore when I click remove I get:

```
this.myList is undefined
```

I've created a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/davidc/rFd7H/ which illustrates my problem.  How should I be removing items from the list?

Comment: The docs say that the function gets the current model value as its argument, but it doesn't say anything about what `this` is bound to. Apparently it's bound to the same thing (well, to a String object instantiated from the string primitive in your array). I would agree that that's pretty lame. However, I'm not sure how Knockout would know to bind `this` to `$parent` ...

Comment: Ok, the docs don't say about 'this' being bound to $parent but this [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) from Steve Sanderson uses it in the same scenario.

Comment: That example uses the pre-2.0 inline event handler code, not the new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can ensure that your handler has the correct value for "this".

1. Build your view model in a function and use `bind` against the current `this` Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/4/.  Or don't build your view model in a function and use `bind` like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/10/
2. Build your view model in a function and keep a variable with the correct value of `this` and use it in your handler. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/5/
3. Bind to the correct context within your binding like: `data-bind="click: $parent.removeFromList.bind($parent)"`  Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/8/
4. Call it as an anonymous function off of the `$parent` object like:  `data-bind="function() { $parent.removeFromList($data); }"`  Generally, not recommended, as it makes the markup ugly/verbose.  Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/9/

Comment: Thanks - this seems to fix the 'this' issue.  However, this still doesn't quite work.  Take your option 1B which I think is the cleanest modification to the existing code (keeping the existing object literal but using bind) - http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/10/.  Remove now gets the correct 'this' but for items created with the addToList function, 'item' is not set correctly, and all the new rows get removed.  Click 'new' a few times and then remove one of the new rows and they all disappear.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Knockout can't write to primitive values in an array.  So, any changes to your values don't actually get written anywhere.  This means that the value of the new ones is always "".  The remove function will remove all matching items.  In this case, it is all the new items.  You would need to do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rFd7H/11/

Comment: Thanks. That Knockout can't write primitive values into an array really should be [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)! Good to know.